# Substring to character comparison counterintuitive results in Julia 1.0

Tags: julia

I am new to the Julia language and see some strange behavior when comparing a substring to a character.

I would think that the first comparison below, at least, should evaluate to `true`.

Could someone please show me how to compare these two values and (bonus) point me in the direction as to why this counterintuitive result is the case?

```
julia> sq = "abcd"

julia> sq[1] == "a"
false

julia> isequal(sq[1],"a")
false
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sq[1]` returns a `Char`. Use `sq[1:1]` to get a `String`.

You can check what `sq[1]` returns in REPL:

```
julia> sq[1]
'a': ASCII/Unicode U+0061 (category Ll: Letter, lowercase)
```

so you have:

```
julia> sq[1] == 'a'
true
```

as this compares `Char` to `Char`.

on the other hand with `sq[1:1]` you have:

```
julia> sq[1:1]
"a"

julia> sq[1:1] == "a"
true
```

The reason for this behavior is that strings are considered as collections. Similarly if you have an array `x = [1,2,3]` you do not expect that `x[1] == [1]` but rather `x[1] == 1`.

Comment: Perfect - thank you - I am too used to the python world where `"A"` and `'A'` mean the same thing!

Comment: The difference in Julia is significant. Creating a new `String` allocates memory, while creating a `Char` does not so it will be faster in hot loops.

Comment: That's nice to know.